# Change color of table cell when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, css, colors, radio-button

I would like for the cell neighboring my radiobutton's cell to be highlighted green when the radio button is checked, and to turn back to grey when it is moved to unchecked.
In other words, the radio button containing the value of the winning team should turn the cell containing that team's name green.

```js
$('input:radio').checked(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id='game_1'>
  <td class='bowl'>Fiesta Bowl</td>
  <td id='radiocell'>
    <input type='radio' name=1 value='Arizona'></input>
  </td>
  <td class='team1'>Arizona</td>
  <td id='radiocell'>
    <input type='radio' name=1 value='Boise State'></input>
  </td>
  <td class='team2'>Boise State</td>
  <td class='gameDay'>January 1</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `<input>` tags are self closing tags.`<input type='radio' name=1 value='Arizona'></input>` ----> `<input type='radio' name=1 value='Arizona' />`

Comment: `.checked` should be `.click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to bind a handler is `.click`, not `.checked`. Then you need to update the classes of the TD's containing all the checkboxes.

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $("input:radio").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("td").toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id='game_1'>
  <td class='bowl'>Fiesta Bowl</td>
  <td id='radiocell'>
    <input type='radio' name=1 value='Arizona'></input>
  </td>
  <td class='team1'>Arizona</td>
  <td id='radiocell'>
    <input type='radio' name=1 value='Boise State'></input>
  </td>
  <td class='team2'>Boise State</td>
  <td class='gameDay'>January 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I have another CSS selector that seems to override your code here. How can I keep both stylings, but have the click action override the following: #sort td{padding: 10px;font-size: 1em; height: 12px; background: #F0F0F0}

Comment: Change this selector to `#sort td.highlight`, so it's more specific.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    $td.siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    $td.next().addClass('highlight');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hszLek0n/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio').change(function( event ) {
    $( "td" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "highlight" );
});
  $( event.target ).closest( "td" ).next("td").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Here is the working example 
http://jsfiddle.net/6bc07guq/